# Understanding functions of matrices

Tags: matrices, functions

Given 
$$f(X) = rank(X) $$
with X being a matrix. Is it possible to visualize such a function? What is the space that it lives in (assuming all entries live in $\mathbb{R}$)?

Is there literature on the topic of functions that work on matrices?

Answer (score 1):

Rank being an integer-valued function, there is not much scope for visualization. You should think of visualizing matrices of fixed rank (for various ranks). But even in $2\times2$ case we have to look inside a 4-dimensional euclidean space. So we are beyond physical space. Not much hope.

Answer (score 1):

The function $X \mapsto \text{rank } X$ is defined for all matrices, but probably it is best regarded as a family of functions $$\Bbb R^{n \times m} \to \Bbb Z,$$ all denoted $\text{rank}$, respectively defined on the spaces of $\Bbb R^{n \times m}$ matrices. The image of these functions are, respectively, $\{0, 1, \ldots, \text{min}(n, m)\}$. (For familiarity, this answer assumes that the involved matrices are real, though we could replace $\Bbb R$ with any field without any harm.)

If we as usual identify the space $\Bbb R^{1 \times 1}$ of $1 \times 1$ matrices with $\Bbb R$. Then $\text{rank}: \Bbb R^{1 \times 1} \to \Bbb Z$ is just the function
$$x \mapsto \left\{\begin{array}{cc}0, & x = 0 \\ 1, & x \neq 0 \end{array}\right.$$

[image]

Similarly, for column and row vectors (that is, respectively, on the spaces $\Bbb R^{n \times 1}$ and $\Bbb R^{1 \times n}$), the rank map takes the value $0$ at the zero vector and the value $1$ at all other vectors. So, the smallest interesting case is that of $2 \times 2$ matrices, but in this case the graph of this function is a subset of $\Bbb R^{2 \times 2} \times \Bbb R \cong \Bbb R^5$, and so it is not so easy to visualize directly!

One can still get a visual feel for the rank function by plotting cross-sections of its graph. For example, if we use the usual matrix coordinates $x_{ij}$ (respectively, the $(i, j)$-entries), then we can identify the intersection of the graph of $\text{rank}: \Bbb R^{2 \times 2} \to \Bbb R$ and the hyperplanes $\{x_{11} = x_{21}\}$ and $\{x_{22} = 0\}$ in $\Bbb R^{2 \times 2} \times \Bbb R$ with the graph of
$$(x, y) \mapsto \text{rank}\pmatrix{x & y\\ x & 0},$$
which is a subset of $\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R \cong \Bbb R^3$.
This function takes the value $2$ where $x, y \neq 0$, the value $1$ where $x = 0$ and $y \neq 0$ and where $x \neq 0$ and $y = 0$, and the value $0$ where $x = y = 0$. Even though this function just represents a cross-section of the function, it captures (and shares) many of the essential features of the function $\text{rank}$ (for this) matrix size: In particular, its image is $\{0, 1, 2\}$, it is [upper semicontinuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity), and it takes on its maximum on an open, dense subset of its domain.